# Docker compose access to port on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running another docker-compose exposing Logstash on port 5044 (using [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)). I'm able to make requests to the service on localhost:5044 on my host, so the port is exposed correctly.

I'm then running another docker-compose (Filebeat) but from there I cannot connect to "localhost:5044". Here is the docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  filebeat:
    build: filebeat/
    networks:
      - elk

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Any cluye why the localhost:5044 is not accessable in this docker compose?

Comment: Do you mean to say that after starting another compose system you were not able to connect to localhost:5044 ?

Comment: can you please post the other compose file too?

Comment: @omu_negru The other compose is available here: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the compose file you linked exposes port 5000, but you say you're trying to connect to port 5044.

Secondly, exposing port 5044 (or 5000) will make the port available to the host machine, not to other containers launched with other compose files.

The way i see it is you can either:

- keep the first service as it is and instead of localhost:port on the secon service use your_ip:port , where your_ip can be retrieved from `ifconfig -a` or something similar and should look like `192.168.x.x`
- Connect both services to an external created network like so:

  - first create the network with `docker network create foo`
  - link the services to the external network in the compose file:

`networks:
      test_network:
         external: true`

Then access change the logstash reference from `localhost:port` to `logstash:port`

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I like the first solution because it separate the two services. If I use my host machines local IP in the filebeat compose service (instead of localhost) it's working as expected. Instead of having to hardcode the IP into this service, is there a docker-way to somehow bind the host local ip into a hostname available on the container?

Comment: not really, unless you do some `grep` foo beforehand and inject the value using an ENV var. That's why i prefer the second solution, since it hides the details of the stack and the logstash service doesn't even need to expose the port

Comment: Okay. In the end my services will run on different machines so the shared external network in docker is not a solution.

Comment: it is, if you use compose v3 and use a [overlay](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) driver instead of bridge. Ofcouse, then you have to init a swarm , but the overhead is not that large